# Using Scrapy to Scrape Data related to Sizes hidden by Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I wish to scrape the details related to the sizes of a product from the following url:

http://www.tennisexpress.com/k-swiss-mens-ultra-express-tennis-shoes-black-fade-and-electric-blue-38191

I'm facing difficulty in finding the information which is inside the Select Size Dropdown on the above page ( 7 - In Stock , 7.5 - In Stock 5+ etc)

In the debugger mode , I can view the bit in the code and am trying to scrape it using the following Xpath, but with no luck.

```
item["Sizes"] = sel.xpath("//select[@name='siz']/option/text()").extract()
```

I think they might be hidden by Ajax. Would appreciate help on this.

Comment: Besides, please go through your previous questions and accept the answers that deserve being accepted (check mark near the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the sizes are located inside the `iframe` which is loaded from a different url. In other words, first, you need to get the url from the `iframe`'s `src` attribute, then make a request to that url and extract the sizes.

Demo (using [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html)):

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.tennisexpress.com/k-swiss-mens-ultra-express-tennis-shoes-black-fade-and-electric-blue-38191
>>> from urlparse import urljoin
>>> url = 'http://www.tennisexpress.com/'
>>> path = response.xpath('//div[@id="prodPurchasing"]/iframe/@src').extract()[0]
>>> url = urljoin(url, path)
>>> fetch(url)
>>> response.xpath("//select[@name='siz']/option/text()").re(r'[\.0-9]+')
[u'7', u'7.5', u'8', u'8.5', u'9', u'9.5', u'10', u'10.5', u'11', u'11.5', u'12', u'13']
```

FYI, to filter out real sizes from the select options, I'm using `re()` here, see:

- http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions

`[\.0-9]+` would match one or more digits or dots.